# How to Get Html Element Attributes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Edit: Everyone went on all kinds of tangents, but the question remains - how do I get an attribute of an html element inside an angular controller?

Here is a plnkr attempt: http://plnkr.co/edit/0VMeFAMEnc0XeQWJiLHm?p=preview

```
    //$scope.myElem = angular.element('testDiv'); //this breaks angular
    $scope.myElem = $document.find('testDiv'); //this doesn't break angular, but unclear what it returns
    $scope.myAttr = $scope.myElem.name; //this returns nothing
```

If you need convincing that this is actually necessary - I need to find when a user scrolls through a div, as is shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/rs3prkfm/ Note that this has nothing to do with the question, simply a scenario. The question is simple - how do I get an attribute's value?

References:
Useless official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element
The only useful link that still doesn't work: http://mlen.io/angular-js/get-element-by-id.html

Comment: you should write a directive and/or use `ng-model` for model binding.

Comment: I don't understand how a directive is relevant at all. Not being rude, just really. Ng-model would get me value, true, I need to change my question. Really looking for atributes, like element.clientHeight.

Comment: a directive will allow you to communicate cleanly with anything.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What benefit is there to me putting the div in a directive...? Are you suggesting its own controller/scope? Why?

Comment: let the div be a directive. Then you can require in the other controller and call functions on it.

Comment: Is this for testing? If not then you should never be accessing elements directly from a controller and directives should only be accessing child elements that are know to exist because they are in its template. Accessing the DOM in a controller is an Angular anti-pattern and should be avoided, always. Also a directive does not need to create a new scope, in fact it is a good practice to only create a new scope when absolutely necessary.

Comment: I don't really get how I handle getting an element's client height then. It's for rewriting this: http://jsfiddle.net/rs3prkfm/ in angular (check when the div has been scrolled through, then do something). I don't see what I would do after I make a directive. Let's say I put my div in a directive, I put the directive where the div was. What's my next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the element api https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

There should be only very few occasions where you would really need it, though.

Comment: Danke schon, aber diese link ist in die Frage.

Comment: Also, unfortunately it doesn't work - plunk added to original post.

Comment: It works pretty well actually. There were a couple of issues with the code. First, the HTML elements had some wrong syntax. Second, the angular app was never run. And the element api does need to receive a dom object. Please see edited plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/zqHMqqiv1rfZk7F1sqbL - hope that will help you to move forward

Comment: Interesting, I solved it like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/0VMeFAMEnc0XeQWJiLHm?p=preview using the article here: http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2014/08/set-attribute-and-remove-attribute.html#.VaghgflVhBe I still think the docs are unclear as ****, but maybe that's just me. Thank you.

Comment: Sooooo....any idea on how to get the clientHeight property by any chance? Not part of the question, you already answered the q.

Comment: You still have some wrong tags in there (<br />, not </br>) which might lead to some unexpected behavior. Despite that, the alert works just fine for me on click and the height is also printed.

Answer (score 1):

You should manipulate the DOM using directives. The controller should only manipulate the data of the application and offer it to the html.

If you have direct manipulation on the Controller you can't, for example, bind several views to the controller. Also, if you change the id of one tag in the html and you are manipuling it directly in you controller, the controller will break.

Read this:

http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use angular.element:

```
var myElem = angular.element("#testDiv"); // here you get your div
var myAttr = myElem.attr("name"); // you get: "testDiv"
```

Remember you have limitations using jqlite. If you want full functionallity of jquery element, import a full "jquery.js" before importing your angular script.

However, to manipulate the DOM you SHOULD use directives as stated by most of the answers.

Comment: I am testing now, will accept answer once done. Selecting a dom attribute isn't considered manipulation though? Or is it? I just need to check it. If it matches x, I run a function that doesn't have anything to do with dom.

Comment: Ok, but why not using something like `ng-click="doSomething("ofThisKind")"` for that? Then in your controller your doSomething function will act according to its parameter

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rs3prkfm/

Need to disable something when user scrolls to bottom of div.

Comment: for that you can use ng-disabled https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled. which can actually be a function that checks the scroll position: `ng-disabled="isScrollBottom()"`

Comment: Of course, but I need to detect when the user scrolls to the bottom to set ng-disabled = "isUserScrolledToBottom"

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, so you may use watchers $watch, or whatever approach you would like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83470/discussion-between-cyberdelphos-and-vso).